# Insert Missing Consecutive Weeks By Group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that contains weekly data. The week starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday. This dataset is also broken out by group.

I want to detect if there are any missing consecutive dates between the start and finish for each group. Here is an example dataset:

```
Week<- as.Date(c('2015-04-13', '2015-04-20', '2015-05-04', '2015-06-29', '2015-07-27', '2015-08-03'))
Group <- c('A', 'A', 'A','B','B','B','B')
Value<- c(2,3,10,4,11,9,8)

df<-data.frame(Week, Group, Value)

df
      Week    Group     Value
2015-04-13        A         2
2015-04-20        A         3
2015-05-04        A        10
2015-06-29        B         4
2015-07-06        B        11
2015-07-27        B         9
2015-08-03        B         8
```

For group B, there is missing data between `2015-07-06` and `2015-07-27`. There is also missing data in group A between `2015-04-20` and `2015-05-04`. I want to add a row for that group and have the value be `NA`. I have many groups and I want my expected output to be below:

```
      Week    Group     Value
2015-04-13        A         2
2015-04-20        A         3
2015-04-27        A        NA
2015-05-04        A        10
2015-06-29        B         4
2015-07-06        B        11
2015-07-13        B        NA
2015-07-20        B        NA
2015-07-27        B         9
2015-08-03        B         8
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Can you share your work so that we can try replicating from our side.

Comment: I provided a reproducible dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `complete` from `tidyr` package, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(Group) %>% 
 complete(Week = seq(min(Week), max(Week), by = 'week'))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 3
> # Groups:   Group [2]
>    Group Week       Value
>    <fct> <date>     <dbl>
>  1 A     2015-04-13     2
>  2 A     2015-04-20     3
>  3 A     2015-04-27    NA
>  4 A     2015-05-04    10
>  5 B     2015-06-29     4
>  6 B     2015-07-06    NA
>  7 B     2015-07-13    NA
>  8 B     2015-07-20    NA
>  9 B     2015-07-27    11
> 10 B     2015-08-03     9
> ```

Comment: This works in my case. For future reference though, the `by = week` section, the default I am assuming is Monday-Sunday. Is there a way to adjust that beforehand just in case my weeks change for future use? For example, let's say my week was from Sunday - Monday?

Comment: @nak5120 the week will start from the min date. So whatever you have as a first day, the week will start there and end 7 days later.

Comment: perfect, that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do this is using an inequality join in SQL.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sqldf)

Week<- as.Date(c('2015-04-13', '2015-04-20', '2015-04-27', '2015-05-04', 
'2015-06-29', '2015-06-07', '2015-07-27', '2015-08-03'))
Group <- c('A', 'A','A', 'A','B','B','B','B')
Value<- c(2,3,2,10,4,11,9,8)

df<-data.frame(Week, Group, Value)

#what are the start and end weeks for each group?
GroupWeeks <- df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(start = min(Week),
            end = max(Week)) 

#What are all the possible weeks?
AllWeeks <- data.frame(Week = seq.Date(min(df$Week), max(df$Week), by = "week"))


#use an inequality join to add rows for every week within the group's range
sqldf("Select AllWeeks.Week, GroupWeeks.[Group], Value
      From AllWeeks inner join GroupWeeks on AllWeeks.Week >= start AND AllWeeks.Week <= end
      left join df on AllWeeks.Week = df.Week and GroupWeeks.[Group] = df.[Group]")
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `seq` function. Here is the code snippet.

**Code:**

```
Week<- as.Date(c('2015-04-13', '2015-04-20', '2015-04-27', '2015-05-04', '2015-06-29','2015-07-06', '2015-07-27', '2015-08-03'))
Group <- c('A', 'A','A', 'A','B','B','B','B')
Value<- c(2,3,2,10,4,11,9,8)

df<-data.frame(Week, Group, Value)

#generate all the missing dates
alldates = seq(min(df$Week[df$Group == 'B']), max(df$Week[df$Group == 'B']), 7)

#filter out the dates that are not present in your dataset
dates = alldates[!(alldates %in% df$Week)]

#add these new dates to a new dataframe and rbind with the old dataframe 
new_df = data.frame(Week = dates,Group = 'B', Value = NA)
df = rbind(df, new_df)
df = df[order(df$Week),]
```

**Output:**

```
         Week Group Value
1  2015-04-13     A     2
2  2015-04-20     A     3
3  2015-04-27     A     2
4  2015-05-04     A    10
5  2015-06-29     B     4
6  2015-07-06     B    11
9  2015-07-13     B    NA
10 2015-07-20     B    NA
7  2015-07-27     B     9
8  2015-08-03     B     8
```